# Write validation metrics on pytorch-ignite ProgressBar on same line

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-ignite

Is there a way to write validation metrics at the end of the progress bar using pytorch-ignite like in keras?

Right now, I'm using ProgressBar.log_message (example below) to print the relevant metrics, but doing so prints on a new line at the end of each epoch. I'd like the messages to print at the end of the bar, without a newline character.

```
@trainer.on(Events.EPOCH_COMPLETED)
def run_evaluator(trainer):
    evaluator.run(val_loader)
    val_metrics = evaluator.state.metrics

    # ProgBar
    pbar.log_message(f"Val_loss: {val_metrics['Val_loss']:.2f}")
    pbar.log_message(f"RMSE: {val_metrics['RMSE']:.2f}")
```

To further clarify, here's the output I'm getting now:

```
Epoch [1/3]: [3/3] 100%|██████████| [00:00/00:00], Train_loss=1.59e+4
Val_loss: 26333.96
RMSE: 72572.66
Epoch [2/3]: [3/3] 100%|██████████| [00:00/00:00], Train_loss=2.35e+4
Val_loss: 25508.46
RMSE: 71426.14
Epoch [3/3]: [3/3] 100%|██████████| [00:00/00:00], Train_loss=2.26e+4
Val_loss: 24721.82
RMSE: 70316.17
```

And here's what I want:

```
Epoch [1/3]: [3/3] 100%|██████████| [00:00/00:00], Train_loss=1.59e+4  Val_loss: 26333.96  RMSE: 72572.66
Epoch [2/3]: [3/3] 100%|██████████| [00:00/00:00], Train_loss=2.35e+4  Val_loss: 25508.46  RMSE: 71426.14
Epoch [3/3]: [3/3] 100%|██████████| [00:00/00:00], Train_loss=2.26e+4  Val_loss: 24721.82  RMSE: 70316.17
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like it is related to tqdm than ignite. Please, ask other questions on github or pytorch discuss forum, our dev team is not on SO. Thanks!